# How do I tell what version of Python a script needs?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm looking at some Python scripts on GitHub, but the developer doesn't specify what version (2.7 or 3.x) of Python is required.

Is there any way to tell? What type of execution errors should I look out for when a Python script fails due to version mismatch?

Comment: Most of the time you can just watch out for print, which is a statement in 2,but a function in 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A version mismatch between Python 2 and 3 is fairly simple to find.

In python 2, `print` is used without brackets, for example: `print "hello"`

While in python 3, `print` is used with brackets, such as: `print("hello")`

Python also frequently has easy-to-read errors for differences in such where the error would end with `did you mean X?`

Also to input something in the command line, python 2 uses `raw_input` while python 3 uses `input`

Answer (score 1):

I found this article useful. It shows almost all syntax differences between python2 and python3. by looking at it you should easily figure out.
[click](https://www.w3resource.com/python/python-2-vs-3.php)

Some other new features like [walrus operator](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/) or [f-string](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/) are also for python3.